# JQGrid: Frozen column creating elements of same id

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using JQGrid and I have few frozen columns with multi-select checkbox. I see there are many div, input types of same id, which is blocking me to implement what I am looking for. For example there are 2 multi-select checkbox with same id i.e. "cb_list".

jqGrid 4.13.5-pre - free jqGrid

Answer (score 0):

The problem with ids is inherited from jqGrid 4.7. Nevertheless, one can select the required element from the frozen div or from non-frozen div without any problems, but the selection is just a little slowly. For example, you can use

```
var $grid = $("#list"); // the grid
...
var $checkAllFrozen = $grid[0].grid.fhDiv
        .find("#cb_" + $grid[0].id);
```

or

```
var $checkAllFrozen = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid-view")
        .children(".frozen-div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv")
        .find("#cb_" + $grid[0].id);
```

to get the "check/uncheck all" checkbox from the frozen div.

If you would need to make any changes in the checkbox you can do there in *both* frozen and non-frozen checkboxes. You can select both by usage

```
var $checkAllFrozen2 = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid-view")
        .find("input.cbox[id=cb_" + $grid[0].id + "]");
```